# How to convert between frequency and period in Pint?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-conversion, pint

I would like to be able to convert between frequency values and period values. These are not directly convertible since they are not exactly the same unit, but I read that there are predefined relationships between units called *Contexts*. However, I can't find which Contexts define which relations and I cannot convert *MHz* to *ns* in the context `'sp'` given in the example:

```
>>> import pint
>>> ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
>>> freq = 25 * ureg.MHz
>>> ureg.enable_contexts('sp')
>>> freq.to('us')
```

gives the error

```
pint.errors.DimensionalityError: Cannot convert from 'megahertz' (1 / [time]) to 'microsecond' ([time])
```

Comment: Spectroscopy defines a relationship between *wavelength* and frequency. You can see its definition in the file example in the docs: https://pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contexts.html#defining-contexts-in-a-file

Comment: My trouble was about finding which Contexts are already predefined and which of those Contexts define which relationships and do we have a predefined context with the relationship `T = 1 / f`. The docs elaborate on the 'sp' Context but don't even hint to others.

Answer (score 1):

The relation between frequency and period is `T = 1 / f`:

```
>>> import pint
>>> ureg = pint.UnitRegistry()
>>> freq = 25 * ureg.MHz
>>> (1 / freq).to('ns')
39.99999999999999 nanosecond
```

Comment: I was rather hoping that you could point me to one Context which includes this relationship, I guess I am going to have to define my own and import it as explained in the docs. Isn't it weird that the simple relationship `T = 1 / f` is not included in any standard Context ?